# show php string containing comma in tag-it input field

Tags: php, string, tag-it

I am using https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it plugin in php page.

Now the problem is, i have a set of string like

```
$str1="AlaqahdariDeh-eShu, Afghanistan";
$str2="`Ohonua, Tonga";
$str3="India";
$str=$str1.",".$str2.",".$str3;
```

which i want to show in tag-it input field like this

```
<input type="text" id="branchText" name="branchText" value="<?php echo $str;?>" class="ui-widget" size="20" style="display: none;">
```

but tag-it also splitting the `$str1` in two value like this
[image]

Can anyone suggest to show `$str1 and $str2` as a two string instead four string in tag-it input field?

Comment: Try to convert comma `,` to html entity `&#44;` in your **tag**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the delimiter when you call `tagit`.

```
$('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
    singleFieldDelimiter: '*'
});
```

Then try:

```
$str=$str1."*".$str2."*".$str3;
```

Or try what @Devendra Bhandari said. Use `htmlentities()` php function:

```
$str1= htmlentities("AlaqahdariDeh-eShu, Afghanistan");
$str2= htmlentities("Ohonua, Tonga");
$str3= htmlentities("India");
$str=$str1.",".$str2.",".$str3;
```